# creating nested dicts in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create the following nested dict structure, `{0: {0: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 1}}` with the following code:

```
feats = {}
for i in range(2):
    feat = feats.get(i, {})
    for j in range(i+1):
        feat[j] = 1
```

but all I'm getting `feats = {}`. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: `{ i:{j:1 for j in range(0,i+1)} for i in range(2)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, you are not storing `feat` value in `feats`, so it is lost after every iteration. At the end of the iterations, `feats` is empty.

You can fix your code like below:

```
feats = {}
for i in range(2):
    feat = feats.get(i, {})
    for j in range(i+1):
        feat[j] = 1
    feats[i] = feat

print(feats)
```

output:

```
{0: {0: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 1: 1}}
```

Comment: Python 3 printing required: print(feats)?

Comment: Thanks, @Hanshan, fixed now.

Comment: You are evaluating `feat` perfectly each time, but you are not storing the value of `feat` into `feats`. So, when you are finished, `feats` remains empty as always. To understand it better, you may consider print the value of `feat` and `feats` after every iteration.

Comment: but `feat` is a reference to a value in `feats`, so it should update automatically, no?

Comment: No, `feat` is a new dictionary, it is not a reference. You could check it by: `print(feat is feats)`

Comment: ok, but wouldn't it be more natural to create an object inside the dictionary and return a reference to it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I ran your program and I printed feats, it printed{0: 1, 1: 1} and not {}

Second thing, what I can understand from your requirement is that, in a generic way, while looping through a range of numbers, you want to have that number as key and value as dictionary containing key value pairs, where number of keys are from 0 to that number and value as 1. Correct me if I am wrong.

So the correct program for this would be:

```
feats = {} 
for i in range(2): 
   feats[i] = feats.get(i, {}) 
   for j in range(0,i+1): 
      feats[i][j] = 1
print feats
```

You can replace 2 with any number in range and get your answer accordingly.